# Adding unique constraint through migration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I am a novice ruby programmer working on a rails api. Problem is api is in production and now I want to add unique constraint to one of the columns in a model. Currently Duplicate entries are allowed and i want to make that column unique.

So I added two fixtures with same name like this :

```
two:
  name: MyString2
  location: 
  status: 2

three:
  name: MyString2
  location:
  status: 1
```

And then I tried to run a migration like this:

```
class AddUniqueToLocationColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  def self.up
    remove_index :locations, column: :name
    add_index :locations, :name, unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :locations, column: :name # remove unique index
    add_index :locations, :name # adds just index, without unique
  end
end
```

But Its showing error: "duplicates exists in database. Migration fails."
Same is the problem. Already I have duplicates in production table. And I want to add a unique constraint to column "name" in table "locations" . How can i make this column unique?

Comment: It is b'coz duplicate records are present in DB, At first delete duplicate records from DB then try to run.

Comment: I want to delete it through a migration. find all the duplicates through a ruby code and destroy them

Answer (score 0):

So you do not want any duplicate names for any two entries in your locations modal but the duplicates already exist? You will have to get rid of the duplicates by either:

1. deleting the data in the model and starting over from scratch
2. deleting the individual locations that have duplicate names
3. changing the names of the locations that are duplicates.

All of which can be done easily in rails/heroku console.

Also, you can add this code into your Locations Model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_presence_of :name
   validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

Comment: 1. I cant start from the scratch as it is in production. 2. deleting indivdually is cumbersome as there are lots of duplicates. 3. Names cannot be changed. Is there any other way like writing some few lines of code in migration itself such that duplicates can be removed and unique constraint can be added?